# How to avoid hardcoding of page name in lightning:navigation?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, bestpractice, lightningnavigation

I need to generate a page URL and use it a link to my page. Users can click on that link and go to the page.

**controller**

```
getPageUrl: function (component) {
        const navService = component.find("navService");
        const pageReference = {
            type: 'comm__namedPage',
            attributes: {
                pageName: "my-page",
                actionName: "view"
            }
        };
        const defaultUrl = "#";
        navService.generateUrl(pageReference)
            .then($A.getCallback(function (url) {
                component.set("v.myPageUrl", url ? url : defaultUrl);
            }), $A.getCallback(function (error) {
                component.set("v.myPageUrl", defaultUrl);
            }));
    }
```

**component**

```
<aura:component>
   <aura:attribute name="myPageUrl" type="String" access="private"/>
   <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.getPageUrl }" />
   <p>Go to <a href="{! v.myPageUrl }">my page</a>.

</aura:component>
```

What bothers me is that the name of the page is hardcoded - `pageName: "my-page"`. Is there a better way or best practice of how to avoid hardcoding in this case?

Answer (score 4):

You can use an auraAttrubute to store the page you want to use.

```
<aura:attribute name="pageName" type="String"/>
```

How can you choose the page to use?

Sorry, but i don't have enough reputation to comment your post, so i used this way :D

Comment: Yes, it might bring in some convenience, yet in this case it still would be hardcoded in the attribute value. What if the page name changes, then you will have to update your lightning component anyways. I am considering storing page names in settings (custom or metadata type), but I am not sure it's worth all the fuss.

Comment: Like i said, it depends of the component usage. if you want to use it as a child component, you can made the attribute public or global